# 500 Error upon login into Plesk Admin - auth.php3?

Tags: debian, plesk

Hello and thanks for reading this,

I'm currently suffering from a 500 error after login to the admin panel on Plesk 11.5.30.

If the incorrect user/pass is input the lgin form returns the correct response.

However upon successful login the page immediately jumps to 500 error.

I've tried using the following command:

```
/usr/bin/sw-engine-cgi -c /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/php.ini -d auto_prepend_file=auth.php3 -u psaadm
```

This returns the following:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required 'auth.php3' (include_path='/opt/psa/admin/plib:/opt/psa/admin/externals') in Unknown on line 0
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-type: text/html
```

Restarting Plesk achieves:

```
/etc/init.d/psa start
[ ok ing psa... [....] Starting Plesk engine pool manager: sw-engine-fpm.
                                                                      done
Starting xinetd service...                                            done
Starting sw-cp-server service...                                      done
Starting mysql service...                                             done
Starting bind9 service...                                             done
Starting postgresql service...                                        done
Starting spamassassin service...                                      done
Plesk: Starting Mail Server...                                        failed
[ ok ing psa... [....] Starting Plesk engine pool manager: sw-engine-fpm.
                                                                      done
Starting drwebd service...                                            failed
```

Bootstrapper repair completes successfully but I still hit the 500 error.

Server details:
Debian 7
Plesk 11.5.30

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Best Wishes
Chris

Comment: Okay - so I solved this.  I will add the answer below later when my rookie timer has expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved this:

1. **Bootstrapper repair** - You must put in the right version number.  Mine was 11.5.30

   /usr/local/psa/bootstrapper/pp11.5.30-bootstrapper/bootstrapper.sh repair
2. FULL **Service stop and restart**

Initially I simply restarted PSA (plesk service) Nginx and Apache.  This was not enough.

So, I moved onto a full service stop and start as below:

```
/etc/init.d/psa stop; /etc/init.d/psa stopall; /etc/init.d/psa startall; /etc/init.d/psa start
```

1. **Login** to the Plesk Panel - be happy!